# Remove the dash based on the number of characters

Tags: python, regex

How can I remove the dash based on the number of characters after and before it?

My code:

1:

```
re.sub(r"(\S)\-", r'\1 ', 'test  10  MF-MT this FOR test')
```

Output: `test  10  MF MT this FOR test`

Here I have removed the dash as I need

2:

```
re.sub(r"(\S)\-", r'\1 ', 'test  10  M-M this FOR test')
```

Output: `test  10  M M this FOR test`

But as you can see here I don't want to remove the dash, so I need to specify two characters after and before the dash to remove it.

I have tried something like this but it did not work

```
re.sub(r"(\S).{2}\-.{2}", r'\1 ', 'test  10  M-M this FOR test')
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew remove the dash based on the number of characters after and before it

Comment: What characters? What result do you expect and why?

Comment: You can use [`([^\s]{2})-([^\s]{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/QQ41fb/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because two characters mean units for me so I don't want to remove any dash on my string only the ones between units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?<=\S\S)-(?=\S\S)
```

To match a dash (hyphen) that is preceded and followed by exactly 2 non-whitespace characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjyTMR/1)

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?<=\S\S)-(?=\S\S)')

>>> reg.sub(' ', 'test  10  MF-MT this FOR test')
'test  10  MF MT this FOR test'

>>> reg.sub(' ', 'test  10  M-M this FOR test')
'test  10  M-M this FOR test'
```

Comment: Why not `([^\s]{2})-([^\s]{2})`?

Comment: Because then we'll have to capture values and use back-references in replacement whereas here we are using just a single space in replacement

Comment: Also note if you want to match complete words of 2 characters then prefer `(?<=\b\S\S)-(?=\S\S\b)`